# Code coverage for test.isrunningtest()

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, issue

```
 if(!test.isrunningtest()){
           try{
          String day = string.valueOf(system.now().adddays(2).day());
          String month = string.valueOf(system.now().adddays(2).month());
          String hour = string.valueOf(system.now().adddays(2).hour());
          String minute = string.valueOf(system.now().adddays(2).minute());
          String second = string.valueOf(system.now().adddays(2).second());
          String year = string.valueOf(system.now().adddays(2).year());
          String strJobName1 = 'Job-' + second + '_' + minute + '_' + hour + '_' + day + '_' + month + '_' + year;
          String strSchedule1 = '0 ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day + ' ' + month + ' ?' + ' ' + year;
          System.debug('@@@@@@@@'+strSchedule1);
          id cronid = System.schedule(strJobName1,strSchedule1, new scheduledTest1(c.id));
          Schedule_Abort__c sb = new  Schedule_Abort__c();
          sb.name = cronid;
          sb.Casenumber__c =c.id;
          Scheduleaborts.add(sb);
            }

            catch(exception e){
            Logger.LogMessageWithException('Exception occurred while Sending Auto Acknowledgement', '', e);

            }
```

Comment: You will never be able to get test coverage for those lines of code... Unless of course you remove the `if(!test.isrunningtest())`

Comment: why is `test.isRunningTest()` even in this prod class?

Answer (score 0):

`test.isrunningtest()` is specifically used to skip codes which will fail during test class execution or doesn't applies to test coverage.

I guess you don't want to schedule your job during test execution that's why you have added it inside `test.isrunningtest()` block.

Just to increase your test coverage, why dont you put ONLY the below code under test.isRunningTest() block?

```
id cronid = System.schedule(strJobName1,strSchedule1, new scheduledTest1(c.id));
Schedule_Abort__c sb = new  Schedule_Abort__c();
sb.name = cronid;
sb.Casenumber__c =c.id;
Scheduleaborts.add(sb);
```

Rest of your code can run safely during the test execution.